# How can I put my name and gender variables into an array?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Student Record Application, I am able to separate the names and genders from the text file, but when I tried putting them into the array, the array would always appear empty. The addStudent method works when I tried it separately.

```
        StudentList list = new StudentList();
        string name = "";
        string gender = "";
        string line = "";
        char[] selected = line.ToCharArray();

        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);


        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        { 
            studentList.Items.Add(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++)
            {
                if (selected[i] != '(')
                {
                    name += selected[i];

                }

                else if (selected[i] == '(')
                {
                    gender += selected[i + 1];
                    break;
                }
                Student student = new Student();

                student.setName(name);
                student.setGender(gender);

                list.addStudent(student);
            }
        }
```

This is the other class I have in order the variables according to the name and gender (Not suppose to change this code)

```
 class Student
{
    private string name;
    private string gender;
    private DateTime birthDate;

    public Student()
    {
        name = null;
        gender = null;
        birthDate = DateTime.Now; // default to set to current date
    }

    public void setName(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setGender(string g)
    {
        gender = g;
    }

    public string getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(DateTime bd)
    {
        birthDate = bd;
    }

    public DateTime getBirthDate()
    {
        return birthDate;
    }

}

class StudentList
{
    private Student[] list;
    private int numStudents;
    private int maxNum;

    public StudentList()
    {
        maxNum = 300;
        list = new Student[maxNum];   
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    public Student getStudent(int index)
    {
        Student ret = null;
        try
        {
            ret = list[index];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Exception has occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public bool addStudent(Student s)
    {
        bool ret = false;

        if (numStudents < maxNum-1 )
        {
            list[numStudents] = s;
            numStudents++;

            ret = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum Students exceeded");

        }

        return ret;
    }

    public int getNumStudents()
    {
        return numStudents;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
            list[i] = null; // set to null

        numStudents = 0;

    }

    public Student findStudent(string name)
    {
        Student ret = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++ )
        {
            Student currentStudent = list[i];

            if (currentStudent.getName() == name)
            {
                ret = currentStudent;
                break;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of an input file structure. You can probably split a line by a character instead of looping through characters in line.

Comment: This is supposed to be a windowsform application, and the StudentList list = new StudentList(); was to create an array which already has another class. - LamaTo

Comment: For example:
Bob (M)
Mary (F)
Kate Jones (F)

-RokX

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `string name = "";`, `string gender = "";` and `selected = line.ToCharArray();` inside the `while` loop. Also you should to create the `Student` object outside the `for` loop.

StudentList list = new StudentList();

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);

string line = "";
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{ 

    string name = "";
    string gender = "";

    char[] selected = line.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++)
    {
        if (selected[i] != '(')
        {
            name += selected[i];

        }

        else if (selected[i] == '(')
        {
            gender += selected[i + 1];
            break;
        }

    }

    Student student = new Student();

    student.setName(name);
    student.setGender(gender);

    list.addStudent(student);
    //Add student objet rather than line string
    studentList.Items.Add(student);
}
```

**UPDATE**
according to your comment I think you should override the `ToString()` method for your Studend `class`

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return name + "("+ gender+")";
}
```

Comment: if i move the string line in this wouldn't work


while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

Comment: It keeps triggering my message box which notifies me the limit of my array. The limit is 300. What is suspect is its adding each individual letter to the array.

Comment: can you please update you post with `StudentList` definition?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to see how the add methods works?

Comment: you  `add ` method is fine, the only thing is you should make sure that your file does not contains more than 300 lines and the `add` method is called outside the `for` loop

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when i try to display just the name



tb_name.Text = list.findStudent(studentList.SelectedItem.ToString()).getName();

Comment: please try to call it like this ((Student)studentList.SelectedItem).getName();

Comment: InvalidCastException

Comment: ah I figure it out, the student list contains strings so you need fill it with Studends. I'll update my answer with needed fixes

Comment: I forgot to say that the student class and studentlist class are not suppose to be changed

Comment: I'm not asking you to change them only how to use. please have a look into the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it ( I didn't compile it so minor mistakes are possible):

```
    StudentList list = new StudentList();
    string line = "";

    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    { 
        string[] lineStudents = line.Split(')');

        foreach(string lineStudent in lineStudents)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            string[] studentProps = lineStudent.Split('(');
            student.setGender(studentProps[1]);
            student.setName(studentProps[0].Trim());
            list.addStudent(student);

        }
    }
```